# interface associates with access point, but dhclient hangs

Tags: networking, wifi, dhclient

I'm having an issue connecting to my access point from the terminal. I'm using `iw` to connect:

```
 iw wlan0 connect MY_AP
```

Running `iwconfig wlan0` shows that it's associated with the access point. But when I run:

```
dhclient wlan0
```

... it seems to just hang at times. Sometimes it connects and gets an IP (70% of the time), other times it will not.

When it does hang, I monitor wireshark, and I'm seeing a lot of broadcasts:

```
137 64.366694000    xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx   Broadcast   ARP 42  Who has 10.138.96.218?  Tell 10.138.96.217
```

Note that the packets are all asking for 10.138.96.218 to tell 10.138.96.217, and they appear a couple of times per second.

Which, if I'm correct is the DNS server asking my computer to respond? I could be wrong.

What could be causing this? When it happens it seems to be unable to connect to the AP for about 5 minutes. I'm thinking maybe my AP can only have a certain number of devices connected, and I have to wait before I can connect? Again I'm guessing.

It appears I don't have an IP address. But not sure why. If the DNS server is asking for my computer to respond, then the AP must have given me an IP at some point?